# Find the points on the graph for which the coordinates are natural numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(2)={3\over2}$ and $2f(n+1)=f(n)+n+1$ for all $n$.
Find the points on the graph of the function $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for which the coordinates are natural numbers, where $$g(n)=\log_2(1+f(n)).$$

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried finding a closed form for $f$?

Comment: I tried to give values, but i didn't find the function. I don't think that this is the way to solve the problem..

Comment: There is a simple closed form for $f$; this is an archetypal example of a recurrence that can be easily solved using generating functions, if you know them, or you could just magically spot how the sequence ${1, 3, 9, 25, 65, 161, 385, 897, 2049, 4609}$ can be expressed.

Comment: No, i didn't learn at school generating functions..

Comment: The function is $f(n+1)=n*2^n+1$?

Comment: That sequence I gave is the numerators of the sequence of $f(n)$, not $f$ itself, but yes.

Comment: Ok, i will try now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that$$2f_{n+1}-2(n+1)+2=f_n-n+1$$Let $h_n=f_n-n+1$ therefore $$2h_{n+1}=h_n$$and $$h_2=\dfrac{1}{2}$$which leads to $$h_n=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}$$or $$f_n=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}+n-1$$finally we have that$$g_n=\log_2(1+f_n)=\log_2(\dfrac{1+n\cdot 2^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}})=\log_2(1+n\cdot 2^{n-1})-(n-1)$$which is an integer iff $\log_2(1+n\cdot 2^{n-1})$ which means that $1+n\cdot 2^{n-1}$ should be a power of two but for $n>1$ this expression is odd and can't be a power of two and for $n=1$ we have $f_1=1$ therefore$$g_1=1$$which is an integer therefore the only $n$ to satisfy the question is $1$.

Comment: I think that $g_0$ works. Can you tell me what is an odd expression?

Comment: I mean $1+n.2^{n-1}$ is odd for $n>1$

Comment: Does this have any demonstration?

Comment: Well for $n>1$, $2^{n-1}$ is even so is $n.2^{n-1}$ and then $n.2^{n-1}+1$ is odd

Comment: Alright, thanks for your effort.